# Use a conditional THEN in a select case to build a view

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to build a view that links several tables.

It is an event schedule listing. One peculiarity of this project is that there is a companies table with an ID and NAME column.

1. If the  mainSubcategory is 217, then I just want to use  companies.name. That works.
2. if the mainSubcategory is 216, I need to :

   Get the company_id from the company_event_associated_companies where the company_id = companies.mainSubcategory

   use that company id to populate the bands column for that record with companies.name where companies.id = company_event_associated_companies.company_id

THE SQL CODE:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW v_events_7 AS
    SELECT company_events.id, 
           companies.city, 
           company_events.start_date, 
           company_events.start_time,
           company_event_associated_companies.company_id,
           CASE
               WHEN companies.mainSubcategory = '217'
                   THEN companies.name 
               WHEN companies.mainSubcategory = '216'
                   THEN companies.name /*This is where I need the name as described above*/
           END Band
    FROM `company_events`
```

UPDATE - The code below is a slight variation of what Panjak provided in his answer. I had to move the ()'s around

```
(CASE
WHEN 
  companies.mainSubcategory = '217'
THEN
  companies.name 
WHEN
  companies.mainSubcategory = '216') AND
  companies.id = company_event_associated_companies.company_id)

THEN
(SELECT companies.name  FROM companies WHERE 
         companies.id = '332')
END ) AS 'Band'
```

Note - I hardwired the companies.id to 332 but I'm sure it will work when I pull the field with the actual company id.

Answer (score 1):

> Please try this query:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW v_events_7 AS
SELECT company_events.id, 
       companies.city, 
       company_events.start_date, 
       company_events.start_time,
       company_event_associated_companies.company_id,
       (CASE WHEN companies.mainSubcategory = '217'
           THEN companies.name 
           WHEN companies.mainSubcategory = '216'
           THEN companies.name
           ELSE (SELECT columnName FROM tableName WHERE 
         companies.mainSubcategory = 'YourData'
 /*This is where I need the name as described above*/ 
   END END) Band
   FROM `company_events`
```

Comment: THANK You!! I made a small revision which I added to the original question as an update. You got me going in the right direction!